# How to create for loop that iterates over multiple arrays and write them onto csv?

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a script that scrapes a webpage that contains four columns, assigns each column's contents to an array, and in the end I want to create a for loop that writes the `i'th` element of each array into their respective columns in a csv.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to create a for loop that will do this. I already have the `f.write()` function written though. I want the spreadsheet to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSrbS.jpg

Here's the code I have so far. Please bare in mind I'm still a beginner:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = input()
uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_css = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_css, "html.parser")

filename = "ge_scrape"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers ="Tag, , Name, , VR, , Value\n"
f.write(headers)

#The following for loops assign values from the columns 'tag', 'name', 'vr', and 'value' to an empty array
#so you can iterate over the arrays and print them in a .csv with a for loop that contains f.write().

tag_array = []
tag_containers = page_soup.findAll("td",{"id":"tag"})
for container in tag_containers:
    tag = container.get_text()
    tag_array.append(tag)

name_array =  []
name_containers = page_soup.findAll("td",{"id":"name"})
for container in name_containers:
    name = container.get_text()
    name_array.append(name)

vr_array =  []
vr_containers = page_soup.findAll("td",{"id":"vr"})
for container in vr_containers:
    vr = container.get_text()
    vr_array.append(vr)

val_array =  []
val_container = page_soup.findAll("td",{"id":"val"})
for container in val_container:
    val = container.get_text()
    val_array.append(val)

#Below is the attempted code:
i = 0
for (tag, name, vr, val) in zip(tag_array, name_array, vr_array, val_array):
    f.write(tag_array[i] + "," + name_array[i] + "," + vr_array[i] + "," + val_array[i] + "\n")
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: what's the url?

Comment: It's input by the user. I'm making this for someone else to use on the job. Every url he'll enter is the exact same webpage with different values in the specified tags, so this script should work regardless. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make a for loop that will reference all of the arrays at the same time and print the i'th element onto a csv before looping again.

Comment: It's nice to be able to test with an url. If lists are equal length you can loop a zip of them of them writing out the resultant list at each turn to csv.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrays/lists are equal length you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the lists and return an iterator of tuples. If lists are different length you might be able to use itertools [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html) and provide a default value for missing.

```
import csv

list_A = [1,2,3,4]
list_B = ['a','b','c','d']
list_C = ['A','B','C','D']
list_D = [99,999,9999,99999]

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'])
    for row in zip(list_A,list_B,list_C,list_D):
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: They are of equal length. I will try this method and get back to you on how it works. Thank you :)

Comment: I just added updated code under the note "#Below is the attempted code:" Does this look like proper utilization of a for loop and the zip() function? Sorry, I'm not able to test the code for a few hours but I'm just curious if the loop looks appropriate.

Comment: nope. You don't need unpacking or the concatenation. Simply, use the result of  for row  in zip(tag_array, name_array, vr_array, val_array): w.writerow(row)    i.e. leave row as the variable name. It is already in the correct format for writing out.